# rst2pdf counter number reuse

Tags: counter, rst2pdf

**I need to re-use a table or image number multiple times**, once in the introductory text, once under the table/image as a caption, and maybe another time as a link to it.

[image: figure]

But every time I use *:counter:`table`* the counter increases by 1.

**How can I freeze the counter for as long as I need to use the same one? In this case at least 2 times.**
Or maybe: How can I get the last counter number?

Comment: So each time you reuse the table it's increasing the Figure # accordingly? I'm pretty sure that's exactly what it's supposed to do. Are you trying to get it to say "Figure 7" for every instance of the identical table/image in the document? Why not just have the table/image in the document just once and refer back to it?